# Mobile Number banned on telegram while scrapping messages

Tags: python, web-scraping, telegram-bot, telethon

I am scrapping political telegram channels' data pertaining to the Russia-Ukraine conflict using Python's telethon library. During the process, my telegram credentials got blocked and now I'm not able to open the application.

Can anyone assist me with the possible reasons? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you may have exceeded a rate limit, it will probably clear up after a while.

Comment: How many messages were you scrapping?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a service, in this case Telegram and its API, you are bound to its terms (in this case, both [Telegram's ToS](https://telegram.org/tos) and [Telegram's API ToS](https://core.telegram.org/api/terms)).

While I'm not a lawyer, they pretty much have the right to do anything with the account, for whatever reason, including banning it, even if your purpose was well-intended.

Your best bet may be [emailing support](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/824). But there's no guarantee the account will remain unbanned depending on your use.